# Only some files are read on app Android

Tags: java, android, file

Good afternoon all of you,
I have 10 files on the same  directory but some of the are being read. 
I've checked the names and they are well written.

The activity recives a int "position" from other activity. It is like an identifier which is used to load a file,whose name is in file "Categorias", I put the names of files available in a string and then with the "position" I read it and  each line of txt are put in position of a List view. The problem is that just some of this files can be read. I can´t see the problem.

first loop of for reads fichero="categorias.txt". second loop reads vector[position]

Thank you

Java

```
protected String fichero="categorias.txt";
protected String Nombre;
protected int position;


protected int contarLineasFichero() {
    int lineas = 0;
    try {
        InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(openFileInput(fichero));
        BufferedReader fich = new BufferedReader(is);

        String s;
        while ((s = fich.readLine()) != null)
            lineas++;

        is.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return lineas;
}

protected void leerFichero() {
    int linea = 0;
    String s;

    try {
        BufferedReader fin =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(openFileInput(fichero)));

        while ((s = fin.readLine()) != null) {

            vector[linea] = s;
            linea++;
        }

        fin.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("Ficheros", "Error al leer fichero desde memoria interna");
    }
}

protected void crearFichero(String auxiliar[]) {

    String s;

    int i;
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter fout = new OutputStreamWriter(
                openFileOutput("fichero1.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));

        /*String [] auxi;
        auxi= new String[3];
        auxi[0]="Piña";
        auxi[1]="Pera";
        auxi[2]="Fresa";
        */

        for (i = 0; i < auxiliar.length; i++) {
            if (auxiliar[i] != null) {
                s = auxiliar[i];
                fout.write(s);
                fout.write("\n");

            }


        }
        // fout.write("Es problema del for");
        fout.close();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("Ficheros", "Error al escribir fichero a memoria interna");
    }


}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_selecciona);

    Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
    Nombre=extras.getString("nombre");
    position= Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("categoria"));

    lvAlimentos = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvAlimentos);
    btCarrito = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btCarrito);
    btContinua = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btContinua);

    contador = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
        int total = contarLineasFichero(); //it counts the lines of a file

        aux = new String[total];

        if (total > 0) {
            //vector = new String[0];
            vector = new String[total];

            leerFichero(); //it reads the file

        } else {
            vector = new String[]{"no va"};
        }
        if(i==0)
        fichero = vector[position];
    }


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, vector);
    lvAlimentos.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Logs:

```
 LOG: 03-13 14:27:37.990    9031-9031/com.example.joan.mypoma W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.example.joan.mypoma/files/alcohol.txt : open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
03-13 14:27:38.000    9031-9031/com.example.joan.mypoma W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
03-13 14:27:38.000    9031-9031/com.example.joan.mypoma W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
03-13 14:27:38.030    9031-9031/com.example.joan.mypoma W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ContextImpl.openFileInput(ContextImpl.java:780)
03-13 14:27:38.030    9031-9031/com.example.joan.mypoma W/System.err﹕ at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileInput(ContextWrapper.java:179)
03-13 14:27:38.040    9031-9031/com.example.joan.mypoma W/System.err﹕ at com.example.joan.mypoma.Selecciona.contarLineasFichero(Selecciona.java:38)
03-13 14:27:38.040    9031-9031/com.example.joan.mypoma W/System.err﹕ at com.example.joan.mypoma.Selecciona.onCreate(Selecciona.java:124)
03-13 14:27:38.040    9031-9031/com.example.joan.mypoma W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
03-13 14:27:38.040    9031-9031/com.example.joan.mypoma W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-13 14:27:38.050    9031-9031/com.example.joan.mypoma W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
03-13 14:27:38.050    9031-9031/com.example.joan.mypoma W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-13 14:27:38.050    9031-9031/com.example.joan.mypoma W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-13 14:27:38.070    9031-9031/com.example.joan.mypoma W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-13 14:27:38.070    9031-9031/com.example.joan.mypoma W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-13 14:27:38.070    9031-9031/com.example.joan.mypoma W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-13 14:27:38.070    9031-9031/com.example.joan.mypoma W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-13 14:27:38.090    9031-9031/com.example.joan.mypoma W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-13 14:27:38.090    9031-9031/com.example.joan.mypoma W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-13 14:27:38.110    9031-9031/com.example.joan.mypoma W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-13 14:27:38.110    9031-9031/com.example.joan.mypoma W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-13 14:27:38.130    9031-9031/com.example.joan.mypoma W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-13 14:27:38.140    9031-9031/com.example.joan.mypoma W/System.err﹕ Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
03-13 14:27:38.180    9031-9031/com.example.joan.mypoma W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
03-13 14:27:38.180    9031-9031/com.example.joan.mypoma W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
03-13 14:27:38.190    9031-9031/com.example.joan.mypoma W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
03-13 14:27:38.190    9031-9031/com.example.joan.mypoma W/System.err﹕ ... 19 more
03-13 14:27:38.240    9031-9031/com.example.joan.mypoma I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.


03-13 13:51:46.746    2048-2048/com.example.joan.mypoma W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.example.joan.mypoma/files/alinos.txt  : open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: `some of the are being read.`. Well ok. But what does that mean? Do you have problems with your code? Any questions? Please put the log in a code block too so the lines do not wrap. They are unreadable now.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  It looks like you're only looking at a single file in this code.  What's not working?

Comment: edited, sorry and thank you

Comment: The error says it: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.example.joan.mypoma/files/alinos.txt  : open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)` Are you sure this file actually exists?

Comment: Yes I'm, and ,moreover, it is at the same folder than others that can be read. The problem is not just with this one.

Comment: Your code creates 'fichero1.txt' and reads 'categorias.txt'. In the log we see other file names which have nothing to do with your code. In the block `for(int i=0;i<2;i++)` you read the same files twice. Why? Your code does not make sense.

Comment: forget fichero1.txt it is not created yet. 

categorias is a file like this:
-example1.txt
-example2.txt
-alcohol.txt

So in the first loop in for i read this file and I put it in the array vector. 
In the second loop of for i read fichero=vector[position] , so, for example, if position=3 I would read alcohol.txt

Comment: My problem is that example1.txt is read but alcohol.txt isn't. They both are at the same directory, I checked names inside "Categorias.tx"t and the rest of files and they are th same.